# Easiest way to initialize a large number of variables

Tags: python, initialization, iterable-unpacking

Assume you are given a large number of variables that need to be initialized to None. A naive way to do this would be to count the number of variables on the left, and create a list of the same size on the right:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j = [None]*10
```

Is there a way to do this without having to count the variables? If one uses this pattern often, it could become tedious to have to count the number of variables.

Comment: Why do you "need to initialize variables to `None`"? Just hold off mentioning each variable until the first time you have a "real" value for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = None
```

Note: don't use this for mutable types. If you're curious why, this demonstrates:

```
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you're not doing this?

```
a = b = c = d = e = f = g = h = i = j = None
```

I'm not too familiar with the intricacies of Python's syntax so please correct me if I'm wrong.